# create a query to display the number of active employees per department per position. mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

hi guys i need help with this mysql exercise, using employees database, https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db
create a query to display the number of active employees per department per position

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free coding / do my homework service. You're expected to demonstrate effort by posting what you've tried, in the form of an [mre] and any error messages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As other people suggested,StackOverflow isn't a free coding / homework service. You should at least give it a shot before seeking for help. Supposing you did your best and the answer still eludes you, here I may provide you with some insight.
I assume the active employees are logged in table `current_dept_emp` whose `to_date` should be 9999-01-01. And in table `titles`, we can find the active emp_no and their title whose to_date is 9999-01-01. Join those two tables we are able to get the number of active employees per department per position:

```
select dept_no, title, count(*) as num_of_emp 
from current_dept_emp c join titles t using(emp_no) 
where c.to_date='9999-01-01' and t.to_date='9999-01-01' 
group by dept_no,title;
```